# What do you call people who use their iphones excessively to the point of distraction?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I'm thinking of the type of person who would text while walking and end up smacking into a telephone pole.  What would you call them?

Comment: I'm sorry; could you just repeat that?

Comment: I guess what you want to call them would depend on the level at which you want to address them or the purpose of doing so. For a few cases, I'd go with *stupid*, *careless*, *selfish*, *dreamer* or *addict*.

Comment: @Diana Just to get a better understanding of your requirement, what is your mother tongue or native language that you most use?

Comment: I think this question is a bit too open-ended. But surely ***distracted*** is as good a word as any.

Comment: @itsols - English!

Comment: Is this subliminal advertising for Apple? Or do you really need the answer for iPhones and iPhones alone?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - sorry to be more specific - looking for a noun rather than an adjective...

Comment: @RegDwight - not for iPhones only, all smartphones!

Comment: @DianaDriscoll please edit your question to give a bit more context, explain that you don't only want a specific make etc.

Comment: OMG - guys, don't be so fussy! I didn't even think of that OP might only refer to iphones (which actually then had to be spelled with an upper P). But for those who are distracted by the cell phone issue, here's what OP is asking: "What do you call people who are using their whatever-cellphones so excessively that they are completely focused on those and do not pay enough attention on their environment any more?" Was that so difficult?

Comment: @Em1 It is much easier for the OP to edit the question than for many people to try to second guess the OP. Reg's request for clarification was only reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of cell phone addiction is called ***nomophobia***.

Wikipedia entry can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomophobia).

Another self-explanatory term is ***crackberry***.

> [***crackberry***](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=crackberry) - someone who is addicted to the use of their smartphones, who don't realize they have been plying with it for hours.

Another term that I have just come across is ***Iphonatic***. Indeed for ***i-fanatics*** there is a website for Iphone accessories called http://www.i-fanatic.com/.

Indeed the urban dictionary defines it as follows:

> A person who is overly attached to his/her iPhone.
>
> *She is such an iphonatic; she takes it into the bathroom. That iphonatic has 200 apps on his iphone.*

Comment: That's probably a post-blackberry term :)